# How to reference a table to itself to bring back employee records and manager giving an empId

Tags: mysql, database

I have no idea how to write a query for this.
I was thinking of a table Union or a Left Table join but I am not sure even how to start

**Employee Table**

Houses both employees and managers

- EmpId is unique
- mgrId is foreignKey to empId

.

```
empId mgrId name   
--------------------not in table 1   0   TheBoss (deleted)
22    1     John   
22    1     John   
22    1     John   
22    1     John   
22    1     John   
45    1     Steve  
45    1     Steve  
68    1     Rudy   
56    22    Lucy
77    22    Mack
78    45    Carlos
79    45    Juan
80    22    James
81    --    Bob    (Bob is staff, but has not been assigned a Manager
82    22    Mike
83    22    Jack
68    1     Rudy   (Rudy is a Manager but no one reports to him)
```

if Manager John(22) is seleted

- Expect 6 records returned Including himself the manager

if Manager Steve(45) is seleted

- Expect 3 records returned Including himself the manager

if Employee Lucy(56) is seleted

- Expect 2 records returned Including herself the employee

if Manager Rudy(68) is seleted

- Expect 1 record returned since no one report to him yet

if Employee Bob(81) is seleted

- Expect 1 record returned since he does not have a manager yet

Comment: This has nothing to do with jquery, query. Please try to select the correct tags in the future.

Comment: *if Employee Lucy(56) is seleted Expect 2 records returned Including herself the employee* ??? I see only 1 row with the value `56` over the whole table.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT empId, mgrId, name
FROM table
WHERE @needed_id IN (empId, mgrId)
```

or

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT t1.empId, t1.mgrId, t1.name
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 ON t2.empId IN (t1.empId, t1.mgrId)
WHERE t2.name = @needed_name
```

PS. If the rows with the same `name` but different `empId` exists then 2nd query is not applicable.